Disable Allow headers in response headers for TRACE request in Spring Boot application
I have a Spring Boot application. When call the curl curl -X TRACE -k https://localhost:9000 -i I get the response:
HTTP/1.1 405
Allow: HEAD, DELETE, POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT
Content-Type: message/http
Content-Length: 83
Date: Tue, 07 May 2024 08:20:44 GMT

TRACE /error HTTP/1.1
host: localhost:9000
user-agent: curl/7.65.0
accept: */*

I want to remove Allow headers from the response or set it to empty.
I implemented an Interceptor to intercept the trace request, but I don't see the request coming here. Other HTTP method request are intercepted except TRACE.
Below is the interceptor prehandle method:
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object requestObj) throws Exception {
log.debug("request url : {}",request.getRequestURI());
if (request.getMethod().equals("TRACE")){
    log.debug("in OPTIONS/TRACE request handler");
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED);
            response.setHeader("Allow", "");
            netConfResponse.put("returnComment", "Method not allowed");
            netConfResponse.put("returnValue", -1);
            netConfResponse.put("success", false);
            response.getWriter().write(netConfResponse.toString());
            return false;
        }
return true;
}

What can I try to achieve this?
